# WebSQL inserts row twice?

Tags: jquery, sql, cordova, jquery-mobile, web-sql

I have straight forward insert query

```
  db.transaction(insertIDB, errorCB);

  function insertIDB(tx) {
   //do some task if else cases to get data

  var sql = 'INSERT INTO data (date, location, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)';
  tx.executeSql(sql, [_date, _location, ...], successDB, errorDB);

  }

  function successDB(transaction, results)   {
    //navigate result page  
  }

  function errorDB(transaction, results)   {
    //print error  
  }
```

somehow it ends up inserting same data twice. Anyone had this issue before. I have even tried setTimeout before navigate after successful insert. timestamps are same second maybe only msecs difference. Any idea to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: If the code is inserting the row twice, then it is being called twice.  One `insert` (of a single row) does not insert multiple rows, unless you have a trigger that does something highly unusual.

Comment: ok, i have checked the code. I have form submit and button click events maybe this is the issue they both calling with i click the button and adding twice?

Comment: no it looks I have this code disabled. What else might call function twice?

Comment: i read that there is async and sync websql operations. Could this be causing this issue?

Comment: . . Put an audit statement before the insert and see if this code is being called twice.  You might have code somewhere else being called; or this function might be called twice.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "audit statement"? or is it simple console.log text to check if it is being called twice? What you said made sense because I have looked through a lot of times before posting here, couldn't make sense out of it. but function is being used twice made sense and i have cleaned code part that might causing this issue. I will test and update here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put some logging on the first line of the insertDB method and check if it logs the message twice, alternatively if it only logs once then you must have another insert statement elsewhere.